# Is there a faster way to convert a column of dates to a column of characters for LARGE data sets? (300 million entires)

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have a date column within a data.table table, which uses the data.table package. The way I convert a column of dates (format is "Date" format) to character would be using the following function:

```
 data[,a:= as.character(a)]
```

Here, we assume that a is a column of dates in the data table "data", which is has 300 million entires in the column a.

However, this takes over 50 GB of RAM, computing power that doesn't come cheap. Is there a better workaround or technique?

Comment: I would consider carefully if coercing Dates to characters is really necessary. It is an expensive operation and I don't think there is much you can do to improve that. Since you probably don't have 300 million unique dates, it would be worth a try, to do this `by a`, i.e., coerce only unique dates to character and copy for all duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-02-01"), by="1 day")

system.time({
DT1 <- data.table(a=rep(dates, 1e4), b=rnorm(32e4))
DT1[, a := as.character(a)]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.03    0.00    3.02 

system.time({
DT2 <- data.table(a=rep(dates, 1e4), b=rnorm(32e4))
DT2[, a := as.character(as.numeric(a))]
DT2[, a := rep(as.character(as.Date(as.numeric(a[1]), origin="1970-01-01")), 
     length(a)), by=a]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.44    0.00    0.44

all.equal(DT1[,a], DT2[,a])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `object 'dates' not found`

Comment: hi, thanks for the post, would you have the dates vector? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on number of unique values of dates in data. It seems there are only 32 unique date values in your example. The second solution easily can be slower by increasing the number of unique dates.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to include `dates`. @djhurio I agree. However, in a dataset of 300 million records the number of unique dates can be expected to be smaller by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: +1 for the idea but I'm a little confused about why you take such a complicated option, I think simply `DT2[, c := as.character(a), by = a][, ":="(a = c, c = NULL)]` works and I'm pretty sure is faster

Comment: @eddi Yes, but won't this need more memory?

Comment: @Roland probably, though that's not completely obvious to me

Answer (score 0):

This was the fastest option in my benchmark:

```
> v=as.Date(sample(18000:19000,1e6,T))
> u=unique(v);as.character(u)[match(v,u)]|>str()
 chr [1:1000000] "2021-05-06" "2021-01-17" "2021-08-27" "2020-04-03" ...
```

Benchmark:

```
v=as.Date(sample(18000:19000,1e6,T))

b=microbenchmark(times=10,
  as.character(seq(min(v),max(v),1))[as.numeric(v-min(v)+1)],
  as.character(v),
  {u=unique(v);as.character(u)[match(v,u)]},
  data.table(x=v)[,y:=as.character(x),by=x]$y,
  {d=data.table(a=v);d[,a:=as.character(as.numeric(a))];d[,a:=rep(as.character(as.Date(as.numeric(a[1]), origin="1970-01-01")),length(a)),by=a]}
)

o=sort(tapply(b$time,b$expr,median))
writeLines(sprintf("%.2f %s",o/min(o),names(o)))
```

The output shows the median time of ten runs relative to the fastest method:

```
1.00 { u = unique(v) as.character(u)[match(v, u)] }
1.05 as.character(seq(min(v), max(v), 1))[as.numeric(v - min(v) + 1)]
2.16 data.table(x = v)[, `:=`(y, as.character(x)), by = x]$y
12.80 { d = data.table(a = v) d[, `:=`(a, as.character(as.numeric(a)))] d[, `:=`(a, rep(as.character(as.Date(as.numeric(a[1]), origin = "1970-01-01")), length(a))), by = a] }
31.77 as.character(v)
```